# Multires: No valid subdivisions found

Tags: sculpting, subdivision-surface, multiresolution

yesterday I wanted to try the new features the awesome Pablo Dobarro provided to the community.
Especially the multires-modifiers new un-subdivide method presented here:

[First video](https://twitter.com/pablodp606/status/1249030743952707586)
[Second video](https://twitter.com/pablodp606/status/1248974189924691969)

Pablo states that:

> "Multires Unsubdivide can rebuild all subdivision levels and
> displacements of basically anything. It works on meshes with
> non-manifolds, triangles, ngons, disconnected elements, and all
> triangles topology."

So I sculpted a mesh with dyntopo and tried to use the multires-modifier afterwards to get a base-mesh with different subdivision-levels out of it.
Sadly, I get the errormessage "Not valid subdivisions found" by the time I press the un-subdivide button.

Afterwards I tried it using just a subdivided cube. This time **it worked perfectly**, however by the time I **added a loopcut to the cube I got the same errormessage.**

Am I doing something wrong, or is this feature only fully supported in the branch Pablo is maintaining?

I used Blender 2.83, 2.91 and the alpha of 2.92 with no avail. Any kind of help is deeply appreciated!